# Oracle timestamp and Interval

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, intervals, systimestamp

I have a requirement to get records from a table that are `systimestamp > LAST_UPDATE_TS + 5 minutes interval`

Could you please help with query?

```
ORACLE DB - 11G Version.
```

I have tried this as below but not working as expected.

```
SYSTIMESTAMP   : 11-MAR-20 06.06.00.070695 AM -05:00
LAST_UPDATE_TS : 11-MAR-20 06.05.50.781167 AM
```

After applying this condition, `systimestamp >  LAST_UPDATE_TS + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE`, 
I expect no data should return, but still i get rows that doesn't satisfy condition.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `LAST_UPDATE_TS`?

Comment: Datatype : Timestamp(6)

Comment: any thoughts/inputs will be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `SYSTIMESTAMP` which is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type to a `TIMESTAMP(6)` data type; this requires a conversion to a time zone.

If you use:

```sql
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
```

The you can see the time zone your session is using.

On db<>fiddle, the default is UTC (+00:00) and running:

```sql
SELECT DUMMY AS query1
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  TIMESTAMP '2020-03-11 06:06:00.070695 -05:00' > TIMESTAMP '2020-03-11 06:05:50.781167' + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | QUERY1 |
> | :----- |
> | X      |
> ```

Since `2020-03-11 06:06:00.070695 -05:00` is greater than `2020-03-11 06:10:50.781167 +00:00`.

If you change the session time zone:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-05:00';
```

and run the same query again (a different column alias was used to prevent caching):

```sql
SELECT DUMMY AS query2
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  TIMESTAMP '2020-03-11 06:06:00.070695 -05:00' > TIMESTAMP '2020-03-11 06:05:50.781167' + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

Then the output has zero rows:

> ```
> | QUERY2 |
> | :----- |
> ```

If you want to manually set the timezone in the conversion then you can use the `FROM_TZ` function:

```sql
SELECT DUMMY AS query3
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  TIMESTAMP '2020-03-11 06:06:00.070695 -05:00' > FROM_TZ( TIMESTAMP '2020-03-11 06:05:50.781167', '-05:00' ) + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

Which, again, outputs zero rows:

> ```
> | QUERY3 |
> | :----- |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aa05e9f739fac039e63a67eab6465a8f)*

Answer (score 1):

`SYSTIMESTAMP` returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value which is compared with a `TIMESTAMP` value.

Actually Oracle is doing this:

```
SYSTIMESTAMP > FROM_TZ(LAST_UPDATE_TS + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE, SESSIONTIMEZONE)
```

Comparison itself is performed on UTC times.

`SYSTIMESTAMP` is returned in the time zone of database server's operating system. If this time zone is equal to your current `SESSIONTIMEZONE` then the condition works as expected.

Either change your session time zone to the time zone of database server's operating system or try this one:

```
LOCALTIMESTAMP > LAST_UPDATE_TS + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

which does not utilize time zones at all.

Comment: Yes, SYSTIMESTAMP returns a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.
It was causing issues when doing the greater condition check.

Answer (score 0):

After checking few forums and other stackoverflow pages, I tried this and it seams to be working now.

```sql
select *
from table
where cast(systimestamp as TIMESTAMP)  > (lst_updt_ts  + interval '3' minute);
```

Comment: This is only correct if the times entered in the `LST_UPDT_TS` column have the same (implicit) time zone as `SYSTIMESTAMP` as all you are doing is discarding the time zone information. If the column has a different time zone then this may compound the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the old way?

systimestamp  -5/(60*24) >  LAST_UPDATE_TS